# How do I sort a computed property in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js, javascript-objects

I am trying to sort columns on a table with rows that are calculated in computed property. However I am receiving the following error:

> "Computed property 'tableData' was assigned but it has no setter.

Here is my computed code:

```
 tableData() {
            let convertedData = this.dataOverview
            let newData = _(convertedData)
            .groupBy('conversationSource')
            .map((objs, key) => ({
                'conversationSource': key,
                'conversationCount': _.sumBy(objs, 'conversationCount'),
                'interactive': _.sumBy(objs, 'interactive'),
                'leads': _.sumBy(objs, 'leadsSent'),
                'merchants': _.size(objs, 'merchantName'),
                'merchantId': _.map(objs, 'merchantId'),
                'leadsPercent': _.round((_.sumBy(objs, 'leadsSent') / _.sumBy(objs, 'interactive') || 0) * 100)
                }))
                .value();
                return newData;
        }
```

And here is the method that I'm using to sort...

```
methods: {
            sortTable(column) {
                let sortedData = []
                sortedData = this.tableData.sort((a, b) => {
                    if (a[column.field] < b[column.field]) { return -1; }
                    if (a[column.field] > b[column.field]) { return 1; }
                    return 0;
                })

                if (!this.sortOptions.currentSortColumn || this.sortOptions.currentSortColumn !== column.field) {
                    this.tableData = sortedData;
                    this.sortOptions.sortAscending = true;
                    this.sortOptions.currentSortColumn = column.field;
                    return;
                }

                this.sortOptions.sortAscending
                    ? this.tableData = sortedData.reverse()
                    : this.tableData = sortedData

                this.sortOptions.sortAscending = !this.sortOptions.sortAscending;
                this.sortOptions.currentSortColumn = column.field;
            }
```

here is my data..

```
props: {
        dataOverview: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {

            convertedData: [],
            currentSort: 'name',
            currentSortDir: 'asc',
            sortOptions: {
                sortAscending: true,
                currentSortColumn: null
            },
```

finally.. here is the template where I'm using tableData

```
<tbody
        class="">
        <tr
          v-for="(row, key) in tableData"
          :key="key"
          class="">
          <td><span>{{ row.conversationSource }}</span></td>
          <td>{{ row.merchants }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.conversationCount }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.interactive }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.leads }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.leadsPercent }}%</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>
```

The sort method worked when I was doing the data manipulation on the mount() lifecycle hook. But this data changes dynamically so mount() wouldn't work.

Comment: Can you show the template binding where you are using `tableData`?

Comment: I think the solution would be to turn `tableSort` into an `(a, b)` function then in your computed property `return newData.sort(this.tableSort)` then your data will always come out sorted.

Comment: @DanielOrmeño updated question with template... Shawn can you show me what  you mean w/ the function?

Comment: well you could use your wrapper now actually but return the `(a, b)` sort function you wrote.
I think it would look something like this

```
sortTable(column) {
  return (a, b) => {
  if (a[column.field] < b[column.field]) { return -1; }
  if (a[column.field] > b[column.field]) { return 1; }
  return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For better styling so I can code. Here is my suggested solution.

#### within methods

```
tableSort(column) {
  return (a, b) => {
    if (a[column.field] < b[column.field]) { return -1; }
    if (a[column.field] > b[column.field]) { return 1; }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

#### within the computed properties

```
tableData() {
    let convertedData = this.dataOverview
    let newData = _(convertedData)
    .groupBy('conversationSource')
    .map((objs, key) => ({
            'conversationSource': key,
            'conversationCount': _.sumBy(objs, 'conversationCount'),
            'interactive': _.sumBy(objs, 'interactive'),
            'leads': _.sumBy(objs, 'leadsSent'),
            'merchants': _.size(objs, 'merchantName'),
            'merchantId': _.map(objs, 'merchantId'),
            'leadsPercent': _.round((_.sumBy(objs, 'leadsSent') / _.sumBy(objs, 'interactive') || 0) * 100)
            }))
            .value();
            return newData.sort(this.tableSort('nameOfColumn'));
}
```

you could even change the sort dynamically by making `nameOfColumn` a variable instead of a constant